# How to Create SkuDetail in Play Billing v3.0

Tags: android, play-billing-library

I am migrating from v1.0 to v3.0 of play billing library.

The code below demonstrates how to launch a purchase flow in v1.0

```
val billingParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSku(skuId).setType(skuType).build()
val billingResult  = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingParams)
```

In version 3.0

it is meant to be done like this:

```
val billingParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetails).build()
val billingResult  = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(activity, billingParams)
```

how do I create skuDetail with skuId and skuType?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use , you pass list of package names and it returns list of `SkuDetails`

```
  suspend fun queryInAppPurchaseSkuDetails(packagesList: List<String>): List<SkuDetails>? {

        val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        params.setSkusList(packagesList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        val skuDetailsResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            billingClient?.querySkuDetails(params.build())
        }
        // Process the result.

        if (skuDetailsResult?.billingResult?.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && packagesList.isNotNullOrEmpty()) {
            val skuDetailsList = skuDetailsResult.skuDetailsList
            return skuDetailsList
        }

        return null
    }
```

Comment: i don't understand this, why do i have to query before getting it?

Comment: I want to launch payment directly, I don't want to query